# Computing an integral in spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

Here, $x$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Could you explain why we can change coordinate in this way? What's the geometric interpretation of $x=r\omega$? (What does $r$ stand for?) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integral $\displaystyle \int\limits_{{|x|}\leqslant{1}}{x^{\alpha}{|x|}^{\lambda}\,dx}$ is a multiple integral over the unit closed ball $$B=\{x\in{\mathbb{R}^n}\colon\;\;\; |x|\leqslant{1}\}=[0,\;1]\times{S^{n-1}}.$$
 In spherical coordinates for $x =r\omega \in B$, we have $r=|x|\in[0,\;1], \;\;\; \omega \in S^{n-1}, \;\;\;dx=r^{n-1}\, dr \, d{\omega}.$

I suppose that integral $\color{red} {\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}{r^{|\alpha|+\lambda+n-1}\,dx}}$ in your book must be written as $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{r^{|\alpha|+\lambda+n-1}\,dr}$ since $r$ varies from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

An arbitrary vector $x\in\mathbb R^n$ is being represented as the product of its length $r=|x|$ and a unit vector $\omega=x/|x|\in S^{n-1}$. The upper integral bound is a typo; it should be $1$, not $\infty$. The coordinate change is performed to allow the dependence on $\lambda$ to be calculated explicitly.

Comment: How do you interpret $\omega^\alpha$ then?

Comment: @Muphrid: I was assuming that $x^\alpha$ and $\omega^\alpha$ refer to products of powers of components determined by a multiindex $\alpha$; that's the only way I can make sense of $|\alpha|$ occurring in the exponent.